# I am getting this error while replicating from mysql to Tarantool these are replicator logs

Tags: mysql, replication, tarantool

```
[2020-11-02 14:49:40] I Connected to Tarantool at 127.0.0.1:3301
[2020-11-02 14:49:41] I Tarantool reported null binlog position. Dumping tables...
[2020-11-02 14:49:41] E Error in reading binlogs: Slave::check_binlog_format(): got invalid binlog format: STATEMENT
[2020-11-02 14:49:41] E Terminating
[2020-11-02 14:49:43] I Connected to Tarantool at 127.0.0.1:3301
[2020-11-02 14:49:44] I Tarantool reported null binlog position. Dumping tables...
[2020-11-02 14:49:44] E Error in reading binlogs: Slave::check_binlog_format(): got invalid binlog format: STATEMENT
[2020-11-02 14:49:44] E Terminating
[2020-11-02 14:49:45] I Connected to Tarantool at 127.0.0.1:3301
[2020-11-02 14:49:46] I Tarantool reported null binlog position. Dumping tables...
[2020-11-02 14:49:46] E Error in reading binlogs: Slave::check_binlog_format(): got invalid binlog format: STATEMENT
[2020-11-02 14:49:46] E Terminating
```

Comment: Without your binlogs sample answer is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Set row-based mysql binary log format.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html

Comment: Its Not Working

Answer (score 0):

Its now working i have tried the thing i have followed this tut
https://www.tarantool.io/en/learn/improving-mysql/
binlog_format = ROW server_id = 1 log-bin=mysql-bin interactive_timeout=3600 wait_timeout=3600 max_allowed_packet=32M